# Avoiding jiggle in palettes

Tags: gui-construction, grid-layouts, windows, palettes

I have a palette containing a `Grid` with dynamics. As it runs it jiggles horizontally. Here's a minimal example:

```
CreatePalette[
 Dynamic[Grid[{{"Some text of unknown length", 
     DateString["SecondShort"]}}, BaseStyle -> 15], 
  UpdateInterval -> 1], Saveable -> False]
```

[image: width of palette wiggles back and forth and depends on the text presented in it]

I don't want to just set `WindowSize` because I don't know the size before it's run, and unfortunately `Grid` doesn't have like an `ImageMargins` or `ImagePadding` or anything like that. I'm sure there must be some simple way of doing this.

Comment: If you don't know the size before it's run, than I think you're out of luck. No matter what size the initial window is, at some point it is possible for the contents to be bigger than the window.

Comment: Would placing your variable width content in `Pane`s of fixed widths help? e.g. `Pane[DateString["SecondShort"], 20, FrameMargins -> 0, 
 ImageMargins -> 0, ContentPadding -> False]`

Comment: Or perhaps a fixed width font. e.g. `Style[DateString["SecondShort"], FontFamily -> "Courier"]`

Comment: @ChipHurst that almost works, but the palette changes size when it wraps around from 59 back to 0... I tried getting the padding form right, but I can't avoid the jiggle :(

Comment: Which one? I don't see the jiggle with `Pane`. For the `Style` idea, padding the string prevents the 59 -> 0 jiggle. `Style[StringPadRight[DateString["SecondShort"], 2, " "], FontFamily -> "Courier"]`

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that the content's size is unknown up front but stays more or less the same later. You can adjust the size after it appears by using current value of WindowSize or to do this up front by using `Rasterize[whatever, "RasterSize"]`.

Let's try with the former one as `Rasterize` needs to be adjusted to use palettes' styles anyway.

```
CreatePalette[
 DynamicModule[{},
  Pane[
   Dynamic[
    Grid[{{"Some text of unknown length", DateString["SecondShort"]}},
      BaseStyle -> 15], UpdateInterval -> 1],
   Full,
   FrameMargins -> 5,
   Alignment -> {Left, Center}
   ],
  SynchronousInitialization -> False,
  Initialization :> (
    CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize] = 
     1.05 AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize]
    )
  ]
 , Saveable -> False

 ]
```

Does it fit your needs?

Comment: Almost, this stops the window of the palette from jiggling. But two things: if I set `SynchronousInitialization->False`, then for some reason some of my FE`oneOfMyDyamicModuleSymbols do not format for a few seconds, which looks bad, and still the numbers in the Grid columns continue to jiggle...